# angular load in dynamic template for a svg

Tags: angularjs, svg, angularjs-ng-repeat

x.Graphic load in the path to the svg image = "./img/house.svg"

The problem is I can't figure out how to load it into the ng-include piece?  Also from what I read it should load inside the `<svg>` tag which is inside the include div.  Any ideas on how to get this to function the way I want to?

```
  <div class="row graphic caption"  ng-repeat="x in myData" ng-show="item ==({{$index}})">

   <div ng-include="{{x.Graphic}}" class="ng-scope">
      <svg width="770" height="500">

      </svg>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cant you just do :

```
<div class="row graphic caption"  ng-repeat="x in myData" ng-show="item ==($index)">
    <img width="770" height="500" src="{{x.Graphic}}">
  </img>
```

Also check if `item == $index` causes graphic not to show
Note:
   try to play with `<object data="blah blah">` as well

Another thing to try :

```
<svg width="770" height="500">
      {{x.Graphic}}
 </svg>
```

Comment: actually I guess that is possible, but I was hoping to load in the svg file so I can animate it.

Comment: How about trying to render directly inside svg tags?

Comment: The only problem with rendering inside the tag itself is that the svg data file is many lines of code so I was hoping to import it as a file path that converts to the actual code so I don't have to see it in the template and my template can be very clean.

Comment: Is ng-include the correct way to approach a possible solution to this?